# I want to import my own flutter package (uploaded on private git server) in my other flutter app by adding dependencis but it doesn't working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I have created my own flutter package and uploaded it on private git server. But I am bot able to access it in my other apps.

I am using this way :
snehal:
git:
url: git@github.com:Snehal-iOS/flutter_package.git

Comment: Have you properly added the SSH keys, also, Provide the Error that you get

Comment: What SSH keys? I did not add anything. Can you please tell me how to add it?
And error it provides is "Target URI doesn't exists" (red error when i import my package..)

Comment: You need to add SSH key for the Github check https://help.github.jp/enterprise/2.11/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

Answer (score 0):

When you use Private Git repositories in your Pubspec dependencies, you need to be able to access those repositories using SSH, it's not needed for public repositories, but will not work without for Private repositories. By the looks of your question you are using github, so you need to setup your github account to access via SSH keys, [check here for how to setup ssh keys in github](https://help.github.jp/enterprise/2.11/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/)